# JQuery location.href - events tracking

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-tracking

I've an offers page with many offers. Client wants to add tracking script to a one particular offer and track clicks on several buttons i.e. "More info", "Share it" and "Buy it".

I want to use the following:

```
if (window.location.href == "www.ddd.xx/theoffer") {
    if $( "#target" ).click(function() { // run tracking script }
    else if $( "#second_target" ).click(function() { // run another tracking script}
    else if $( "#third_target" ).click(function() { // run another tracking script } };
```

does it look ok?

I will highly appreciate ur help!
BR,
Newbie

Comment: Have you tried it? What's not working? It's difficult to say if this is correct or not without seeing more context.

Comment: Remove the `if` and `else if` statements and it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks Rory, should I remove all if and else if or only the ones inside of the first if?

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering if you are tracking your target page or current page.`window.location.href` means your current page url, or you can set it to jump to another page.

But no matter which page are you tracking, you should bind the `click` function with buttons first.

For current page, you can bind like this:

```
$( "#target" ).click(function() { // run tracking script });
$( "#second_target" ).click(function() { // run another tracking script});
$( "#third_target" ).click(function() { // run another tracking script});
```

This function are callbacks and wont run the tracking directly.It will only be triggered after you clicked the right button.

If you have a lot of buttons to do some similar work, seems you can add `class="track_button"` to all the `<button>`s, and bind like this:

```
$(".track_button").click(function(){
  if (window.location.href == "www.dd/xx/the_offer") {
    var curId = $(this).attr("id");
    if(curId == "target"){
      //do tracking 1
    }
    else if(....){
      //do tracking n....
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Actually I dont know what do you want to do with the `href`.For function binding, check this: http://jsfiddle.net/o0d12vpr/

Comment: i need href to make sure a user is on the selected offer page when clicking these buttons. Otherwise it'd track clicks from all other offers pages.

Comment: Well. So I think my code snnipet 2 suits for you. Just try it and update your   questions and let me know if I can help.